# Looking for an opensource ecommerce solution with quick checkout workflow

Tags: open-source, ecommerce

I see a lot of site with quick checkout workflow. You choose your product and you go directly to the checkout page to pay often without having to authenticate. In general, you receive an email when you have paid with instruction to create an account and/or provide your delivery address for physical goods.

I have some knowledge in Magento but I think I will have to break down this software if I want to build this kind of checkout workflow or something simple like that.

Do you have some recommendation about an open source (prerequisite) ecommerce solution in any language providing this kind of functionnality ? Or should I develop my own ?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Commerce KickStart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), which is a [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal) "distribution". Some more details about it (from the linked page):

> Commerce Kickstart is the quickest way to get up and running with [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce). It includes the latest versions of Drupal core, Drupal Commerce, and the other modules it depends on. It also gives you a set of options to create a fully-featured demo store out of the box complete with an attractive theme, catalog and search configuration, and a custom back office interface.

If you rather want a (way more) basic solution, then have a look at [Basic Cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic_cart) (a contributed module for [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal)). For more details on that, refer to my answer to the question "[Is there a one page shopping cart for Drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167302/is-there-a-one-page-shopping-cart-for-drupal/167307#167307)".

To be complete, there is also [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com), a SO-site dedicated to Drupal, which has tons of questions (and great answers) about topics such as [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and/or [Commerce KickStart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).

Comment: It does not indicate that it provides out of the box the kind of workflow I want to implement so I don't think it is relevant in my case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I Extended my answer a bit (with the "Basic Cart" paragraph I added).

Comment: Thx. I will look into it.